# Running into an infinite while loop

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

I'm running into an infinite loop here. I need help finding an edge case here, that I might not have considered.

`table` is an array of (key, value) pairs. `isRemoved()` flags an element of table, if it has been removed.

`index` is derived from the hashing function of 'key'... Here I'm trying to add an element to the hash table.

```
int removed = -1;
            while (table[index] != null) {
                if (table[index].isRemoved()) {
                    if (removed != -1) {
                        removed = index;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (key.equals(table[index].getKey())) {
                        dData = table[index].getValue();
                        table[index].setValue(value);
                        return dData;
                    } else {
                        index++;
                        index %= startingSize;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (removed != -1) {
                index = removed;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your logic is not adding an element but updating an existing value.
- Also, you have a circular logic. Get rid of "index %= startingSize;"
- Are you certain that the table[index] will be null when index reaches the table size?

Comment: Your initial question says "Here I'm trying to add an element to the hash table" . Anyway, why do you want to go back to zero and start all over again when you realized there were no collisions on first pass? Do you expect the table to be updated in a separate thread then obviously synchronization part is not taken care.

Answer (score 0):

In this first `if`

```
if (table[index].isRemoved()) {
                if (removed != -1) {
                    removed = index;
                }
}
```

index is not being increment and no other code is be accessed